# How to notify scaled instances of a particular service about changes in DB?

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq, microservices, message-queue, horizontal-scaling

I've a particular microservice, and due to highload it scaled out. Has a load balancer and API gateway. Clients are distributed between instances in a round robin manner. Some client perform a change on a particular instance. The instance stored the change to DB. How to push other instances to read the change?

My thoughts are: use a message queue ( Kafka or Rabbit) is it a viable solution? If yes, please suggest the MQ's topology which is the most appropriate to this problem?